# Platform for SDN-WSNs (Softwared Defined Networking for Wireless Sensor Networks)

Tags: networking, cross-platform

I'm looking for a platform for building and managing a SDN-WSN network, more specifically:

1. A platform that runs on Windows (Linux is also alright).
2. A platform that is continiously mantained.
3. An UI attached to it would be awesome.
4. Have the possibility to change different parameters of a sensor.
5. Be able to use RYU controllers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: @Izzy just edited the question, hope that's fine now!

Comment: Thanks – and yes, it is! Additional details *might* be needed – but as this is not exactly my area of proficience, those who's it is must raise them if needed. Good luck!